# Question on optimization algorithm to train peculiar regression

Tags: optimization, regression

I've been in my operations research course, and we have been working on
optimization in particular problems within regression. We hypothesize that
for variables $h,s,d,t,$ there is this set relationship between them:
$$h = \beta_s e^{s^2} + \beta_d d\sin(-\beta_t t) + \beta_0 + \epsilon,$$
where $\epsilon \sim Normal(0,\sigma^2)$. I am supposed to figure out a
reasonable solution for finding our $\beta$'s given our training sample set
$\{<h_n,s_n,d_n,t_n>\}$. My professor has recommended that we use a
squared-error loss function, i.e.
$$L(\mathbf{h},\mathbf{\hat{h}}) = \sum_{i=1}^n (h_i - \hat{h}_i)^2.$$
Given this, I would have liked to have had a closed form for directly
calculating the $\beta$'s (like there is in standard linear regression), but
given the nonlinearities present in this model, I have not been able to find a
simple closed-form solution for cases like this. Hence, I have decided to
find some algorithm to calculate this, but I have been told that standard
gradient descent on the loss function is not going to help me in this
non-linear situation due to the high likelihood of reaching a local minimum
(rather than a global minimum). I would ask, is there another method within
operations research that will be useful for training an extremely non-linear
regression like this? As a reference, the gradient of this function will be
this:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \beta_0} = \sum_{i=1}^n 2(h_i - \hat{h}_i) \times
(-1)$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \beta_s}= \sum_{i=1}^n 2(h_i-\hat{h}_i) \times
    (-e^{s_i^2})$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \beta_d}=\sum_{i=1}^n 2(h_i-\hat{h}_i)
    \times -d_i \sin(-\beta_t t_i)$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \beta_t} =\sum_{i=1}^n 2(h_i - \hat{h}_i)
\times -\beta_d d_i \cos(-\beta_t t_i) \times (-t_i).$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have $n$ data points $(s_i,d_i,t_i,h_i)$ and the model $$h = \beta_s e^{s^2} + \beta_d d\sin(-\beta_t t) + \beta_0 $$ you already notice that the model is nonlinear; closed form formulae are not possible to obtain and only numerical methods could be used. Nonlinear regression being required, you need to start with "reasonable" estimates and this is a problem.

However, you can make the problem simpler noticing that the model is nonlinear just because of parameter $\beta_t$. If you fix it to a given arbitrary value, parameters $\beta_s,\beta_d,\beta_0$ are immediately obtained using multilinear regression( regressors being $e^{s_i^2}$ and $d_i\sin(-\beta_t t_i)$).

The values of these three parameters are implicit functions of $\beta_t$.

Doing it you have

$$L(\mathbf{h},\mathbf{\hat{h}}) = \sum_{i=1}^n (h_i - \hat{h}_i)^2=\Phi(\beta_t)$$ Try a series of values of $\beta_t$ until you see more or less $\Phi(\beta_t)$ going through a minimum. Now, you have your estimates with which you can start the nonlinear regression.

You could even skip the nonlinear regression solving numerically $\Phi'(\beta_t)=0$ that is to say searching graphically the solution of ,say, $$\Phi(1.001\beta_t)-\Phi(0.999\beta_t)=0$$